# Select em 2 tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

PHP PDO MySQL
A questao é a seguinte, eu tenho duas tabelas, uma chama grupos e a outra membro_grupos, vou dar uma resumida nas tabelas, eu consigo pegar os grupos e mostrar quantos usuarios cada grupo tem, mas para mostrar quantos usuarios tem em cada grupo eu preciso dar um rowCount() na tabela de membros, pq na tabela de membros é basicamente isso (id, idgrupo, idusuario) entao se eu tiver 10 usuarios em um grupo vou ter 10 linhas assim entao pego o resultado do rowcount que é o numero de membros, mas eu quero mostrar os 5 grupos com mais membros, como eu vou fazer isso? se os dados estivesse todos na mesma tabela ex, grupo 1 tem 30 membros, eu daria um order by membros desc 5 e funcionaria, mas como os registros estao em outra tabela como eu vou fazer isso? eu nao posso simplesmente dar um order by na outra tabela, pq la tbm os registros nao estao em uma unica linha, cada membro tem uma linha em um grupo, eu fiz da seguinte forma.

funcao que pega os grupos(mas ela ordena pelo id quero ordenar por qual tem mais usuarios)

```
public function ultimosGrupos($limite){
    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM groups ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT :limite";
        $this->Select = $this->Conn->prepare($query);
        $this->Select->bindParam(':limite' , $limite, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->Select->execute();
        if($this->Select->rowCount() > 0){
            return $this->Select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        exibeMensagens("Erro ao consultar. {$exc->getMessage()}", WS_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Agora tem a funcao de contar quantos registros de usuario tem em cada grupo

```
public function users_por_grupo($id){
        try {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM group_memberships WHERE group_id = :id";
            $this->Select = $this->Conn->prepare($query);
            $this->Select->bindParam(':id' , $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $this->Select->execute();
            return $this->Select->rowCount();
        } catch (PDOException $exc) {
            exibeMensagens("Erro ao consultar. {$exc->getMessage()}", WS_ERROR);
        }
    }

tabela grupo (
id
nome
dono
created
)

tabela membrosgrupo(
id
idgrupo
idusuario
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, Martins.

Não é preciso usar row_count nem nada, você pode usar as funções do próprio SQL, como a COUNT a GROUP BY e fazendo um relacionamento entre as duas tabelas usando LEFT JOIN. Dessa forma, você consegue fazer apenas uma query e acessar todos os dados que você deseja já formatados. Para resgatar o TOP 5 de grupos com mais membros, ficaria assim.

```
SELECT
  grupos.nome,
  COUNT(*) as total_membros
FROM
  grupos
LEFT JOIN
  membros
ON
  grupos.id = membros.idgrupo
GROUP BY
  grupos.nome
ORDER BY
  total_membros DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Isso vai te voltar uma tabela, onde a primeira coluna é o nome do Grupo e a segunda a quantidade de membros presente em cada um deles.

Veja funcionando no JDOODLE: https://www.jdoodle.com/a/106M

Comment: Mas dessa forma eu consigo ordernar por grupos com mais pessoas?

Comment: Opa, acabei esquecendo dessa parte. Mas você pode sim. Basta inserir `ORDER BY total_membros DESC`. Dessa forma você os ordena de forma decrescente. Você comentou em colocar os 5 grupos com mais membros correto? Nesse caso, a função LIMIT também tem de ser usada. Vou modificar a reposta para acrescentar isso ;D

Comment: mais tipo, eu nao sei se vc entendeu o problema, a questao é que nao existe um campo na tabela membrosgrupo chamada total_membros, existe apenas id, idgrupo e idusuario, entao eu nao tenho uma linha assim: (1, grupo(2), usuario(6)) 

No caso eu nao tenho um campo falando o grupo id 1 tem tantos usuarios, eu tenho sao varias linhas faando que o usuario x é membro do grupo x, vou mandar uma foto pra vc visualizar melhor,

print da tabela com os usuarios de cada grupo https://prnt.sc/mnbfow

Comment: `total_membros` não é um campo da tabela, é uma variável que foi criada usando a função COUNT(*) que, da forma que está sendo chamada na query, acaba por contar a quantidade de usuários que estão em determinado grupo. Execute o exemplo que eu coloquei na resposta e veja se está de acordo com sua modelagem.

Comment: a sim, vou tentar aqui, muito obrigado

Comment: Funcionou, eu demorei pra responder pq tive que sair, mas funcionou cara, muito obrigado, so tive que alterar a posicao do Count que estava acusando erro de syntax, mas muito obrigado, ficou assim

SELECT COUNT(*) as total_membros , groups.name FROM groups LEFT JOIN group_memberships ON groups.id = group_memberships.group_id GROUP BY groups.name ORDER BY total_membros DESC LIMIT 5;

Comment: Show, se puder marcar a pergunta como respondida, agradeço ;D